# Image Constructor Not Showing In Main Class

Tags: oop, javafx

I am incredibly new to JavaFX so this might have an obvious answer, apologies. But I've started attempting object oriented programming and I tried creating a sprite class that allows the user to add an image file in the constructor. This was hopefully supposed to make it easier to add the images into the main start method, however, my image is not showing at all no matter what I do.

**Main Class**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.Group;

public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite("https://art.pixilart.com/36ba3b65e7e9f5d.png");
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(sprite);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("A Simple Scene!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Sprite Class**

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Sprite extends Group {

    public Sprite(String file) {
        Image img = new Image("https://art.pixilart.com/36ba3b65e7e9f5d.png"+file, 0, 80, true, false);
        ImageView character = new ImageView();
        character.setImage(img);
        this.getChildren().add(character);
    }
}
```

I've looked up different tutorials and have tried to edit the code according to that, but it still does not show the image. It shows everything else just fine, though.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: `"https://art.pixilart.com/36ba3b65e7e9f5d.png"+file` - why are you using `image url string + file`?

Comment: If something goes wrong with loading an image (as has occurred here),  you can use the [error](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#isError()) and [exception](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getException()) properties of the image to diagnose what went wrong.

Comment: You might also want to [load your image from a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) which you have downloaded and packaged with your application, rather than always fetching the image from the internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other)

Comment: I'm confused by the Sprite class.  Why put an ImageView into a Group all by itself?  Why not just use ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
Image img = new Image("https://art.pixilart.com/36ba3b65e7e9f5d.png"+file...
```

to

```
Image img = new Image(file....
```

Because you already pass the URL in 'String file'.